# Deploy encrypted password on Windows 10 without key

Tags: linux, powershell, security, encryption, passwords

I've previously been using mkpasswd to encrypt a password on Linux, and piping it to chpasswd to set the password of a new user.

I run mkpasswd standalone on a machine:

```
$ printf "s£cr3t" | mkpasswd --stdin --method=sha-512 --salt "salt"
```

The encrypted password is then deployed along with a script to set the password.

```
printf "user:-the-encrypted-password-" | sudo chpasswd --encrypted
```

So the original plain text password is never deployed.

Is it possible to do a similar thing on Windows 10?  I've been reading up on Powershell's ConvertTo-SecureString and ConvertFrom-SecureString, but if I don't use a key that will only work on the same machine. And if I use a key, I'll have to deploy the key as well, which is just as bad a plain text password.

In summary - I'd like to deploy an encrypted password on Windows 10 that can be stored without the need to decrypt it.

Comment: SHA-512 isn't encryption it's a hasing algorithm.  Which means you cannot decrypt a blob of data protected by SHA-512.  What you worked, worked, because of how passwords are stored in Linux. There is not equivlancy on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that passwords are generally not *encrypted* (which implies a reversible function) but rather *hashed* (which is irreversible). As such, `SecureString` and its companion cmdlets `ConvertTo-SecureString` and `ConvertFrom-SecureString` are of no use—they only deal with reversible encryption.

The SHA-512 hash you want is also only part of the equation. Because rainbow tables are a thing, proper use of hashes for passwords involves an additional random component, called *salt*. (You should not pass the salt manually because weak values can compromise the overall cryptographic strength.)

Let’s take a look at the `mkpasswd --method=sha-512` output (for password “banana”), which could also appear in `/etc/shadow` like this:

```
$6$mcD2hLIMJToO/6p.$BOERIGcczwhLazvF3LWumZCsNPE1LQ4dnPp4vZmevgHCNV/FuPTBb.7whQf5PVGa3S2pRpIP1Tiy1CzzuA/271
```

There are multiple components, separated by dollar signs:

- `6`, the scheme (SHA-512); various other schemes exist
- `mcD2hLIMJToO/6p.`, the salt
- `BOERIGcczwhLazvF3LWumZCsNPE1LQ4dnPp4vZmevgHCNV/FuPTBb.7whQf5PVGa3S2pRpIP1Tiy1CzzuA/271`, the actual hash

The algorithm is [documented here](https://akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt). Technically, it is possible to implement this in any sensible language (including PowerShell), provided the required cryptographic functions are available. However, it is convoluted, so don’t bother. There’s [a related question in verifying a password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60828320) on Stack Overflow, it links to [a C# implementation](https://gist.github.com/ygoe/33832285434eac3dc299a2b821470d19). You could use that.

---

So now that we determined you won’t be doing this in PowerShell, what *is* the solution? Use `mkpasswd`! There are various ways to run Linux tools on Windows. The most obvious is WSL. Just use *the real thing*™. A full virtual machine is also a possibility. Furthermore, OpenSSL can also do it, Windows builds are available.

Comment: I almost feel like opening a question on StackOverflow on your 1st paragraph about that statement as it really seems to oversimplify the use of `SecureString` and the other PowerShell cmdlets. Because `/etc/shadow` is a file storing passwords in a file. Whereas `SecureString` the security is more about protecting the data in memory and during the execution of scripts rather than long-term storage of a password value saved in a file. Throwing in `Get-Credential` gives you the secure way to use files tied to user-machine pair per answers I've written out there on SU posts.